# convert formurl encoded input data to json property in php

Tags: php

My code is as shown below:

```
<?php
  $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $postData = json_decode($json, true);
  error_log($json);
  $orderId = $postData["orderId"]; 
  error_log("order id is".$orderId);

?>
```

Now first error_log prints the data as customerPhone✆=1234567890&orderAmount=1000&orderId=442

But somehow $postData is not able to process it properly and because of which second error_log does not give me any output .

Comment: that is GET data

Comment: with so many SO points I'm surprised your question is so broad and without example of what you've tried so far ...

Comment: @moped i have updated the question with the code

Comment: and where is the json? because the string you're getting from php input is not json .. have a look at GET/POST/REQUEST - how it works and how to access variables
+ instead of json_decode, you should just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php